# A Doubt about Well Ordering Principle and Principle of Mathematical Induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction, natural-numbers, well-orders

I have had this lingering doubt in my mind for a very long time: One of the standard constructions of N starts by assuming the 5 Peano Axioms, proving that every non-zero is a successor and s(n) is not equal to n for any n. Then one establishes the recursion theorem leading to addition, multiplication the usual laws, then order and trichotomy and finally WOP.
Now most books "prove the equivalence of WOP and PMI and PCI."

My question is: While proving WOP implies PMI we need to assume that if n is not 0 then it  is a successor. Are we justified?

My next question is what is the order one is considering. If it is the usual order then are we not assuming too much: Addition, Multiplication etc.?

It would be logically clearer if we knock PMI from PA, replace it with WOP with some total order plus one or two additional assumptions like 0 is the least and every non zero is a succesor and simply prove PMI. Is this possible?

Finally how would this new order relate to the usual order (since after PMI is established the usual game can be played.)

Answer will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's the usual order

Comment: After I posted the question I came across this 2019) article: Öhman, L. Are Induction and Well-Ordering Equivalent?. Math Intelligencer 41, 33–40 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-019-09898-4  and I think it answers some of my Qns. Have to read it.

Comment: See also the questions listed under "Related" on this page.

Comment: Your question has inspired me to try to formalize the theorem in question. I have assembled most if not all of the required parts and continue to "clean it up" and restructure it to make them more readable for my blog. If you start with all 5 of Peano's Axioms, you must next construct the addition function and the partial ordering on N. This ordering is referred to in the usual  statement of the theorem and is not just an arbitrary relation. As such, the statement of the theorem must give you more information about that ordering. Without that information, it seems you can't prove the converse.

Comment: See my question today at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145944/proposed-structure-of-a-formal-proof-for-equivalence-of-induction-and-the-well-o